# Edit DataTables source data, using form inside pop-up window

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel, datatables

I have a datatable that fetches records from database with ajax. I want to add the edit tooltip like [jquery-datatables-editor](/questions/tagged/jquery-datatables-editor) extension to [datatables](/questions/tagged/datatables) but for free. Is there any plugin to do this? if not, can any one help me to do this manually?

This is my JavaScript code:

```
$('#table_id').DataTable({
    "serverSide": true,
    "processing": true,
    "ajax": function (data, callback, settings) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/some url',
            type: 'GET',
            data: data,
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data)
            }
        });

    },
    "columns": [{
            "title": "edit",
            "data": null,
            "className": "center",
            "defaultContent": '<a href = "" class = "editor_edit"> Edit </a>  /  <a href = "" class = "editor_remove"> Delete </a>'
        }, {
            "title": "name",
            "data": "name"
        }, {
            "title": "id",
            "data": "id"
        },

    ]
});
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. any of answers couldn't help me and were not exact answer. but some part of your answer was really helpful.

Answer (score 11):

Since your question (and posted code sample) are mostly concerned with front-end part of editable rows feature I will focus on that primarily as backend logic is pretty much straightforward (update/insert data into storage upon AJAX-request receipt).

In order to implement that feature following logic I may suggest:

- append (by means of [`createdRow`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/createdRow) option) some anchor ([`row().index()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/row().index()) or source object `id` property, etc) to your source data within some `<tr>` attribute (e.g. `rowindex`), so you will know later on which entry to modify server-side:

```
$('table').DataTable({
    ...
    createdRow: (tr, _, rowIndex) => $(tr).attr('rowindex', rowIndex)
})
```

- append some anchor attribute (e.g. `data-src`) to your editor pop-up (I'll use [bootstrap-4](/questions/tagged/bootstrap-4) modal for that purpose) `<input>` nodes to link those input fields to corresponding source object properties:

```
<div><label>PropertyX:</label><input data-src="propertyX"></input></div>
```

- upon clicking <kbd>edit</kbd> button, grab corresponding row data, populate editor pop-up `<input>` fields with that data, pass anchor to edited row (`rowindex` attribute value) over to pop-up attribute:

```
//for table id 'example' handle clicking 
//edit button having class 'edit'
$('#example').on('click', '.edit', function () {
    //get clicked row invoking row() API method
    //against DataTables object assigned to dataTable
    const rowClicked = dataTable.row($(this).closest('tr'));
    //populate edit form with row data by corresponding
    //rowClicked property based on 'data-src' attribute
    $.each($('#editform input'), function () {
        $(this).val(rowClicked.data()[$(this).attr('data-src')]);
    });
    //set modal attribute rowindex to corresponding row index
    $('#editform').attr('rowindex', rowClicked.index());
    //open up edit form modal
    $('#editform').modal('toggle');
});
```

- upon completing row data editing, store `<input>` values into object:

```
const modifiedData = {};
$.each($('#editform input'), function(){
  Object.assign(modifiedData, {[$(this).attr('data-src')]:$(this).val()});
});
```

- `POST` data (along with corresponding `rowindex`) to the server and reload ([`ajax.reload()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.reload())) up-to-date datatable upon success:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/editrow',
    method: 'POST',
    data: {id: $('#editform').attr('rowindex'), ...modifiedData},
    success: () => {
        $('#editform').modal('hide');
        dataTable.ajax.reload();
    }
});
```

Complete **live demo** of that method you might examine in your browser's DevTools by the following [link](https://fmgrt.sse.codesandbox.io/) with some bonus in form of row <kbd>delete</kbd> button.

Both HTML and jQuery code sample might look as follows (**not executable** as there's no supporting backend):

```js
$(document).ready(() => {

  //data table initialization
  const dataTable = $('#example').DataTable({
    ajax: {
      url: '/getdata',
      type: 'GET',
      dataSrc: ''
    },
    dom: 't',
    //use <tr> attribute 'rowindex' to anchor to source data row index
    createdRow: (tr, _, rowIndex) => $(tr).attr('rowindex', rowIndex),
    columns: [ 
      {data: 'name', title: 'Name'},
      //append 'Edit'/'Delete' buttons to the rightmost edge of the cell
      {data: 'title', title: 'Title', render: (cellData, _, __, meta) => cellData+'<i class="delete fa fa-trash"></i><i class="edit fa fa-pencil"></i></button>'}
    ],
  });
  //delete button handler
  $('#example').on('click', '.delete', function() {
    //extract the index of the row to delete
    //from 'rowindex' attribute
    const rowIndex = $(this)
      .closest('tr')
      .attr('rowindex');
    //do AJAX-call to the backend
    $.ajax({
      url: '/deleterow',
      method: 'DELETE',
      data: {id: rowIndex},
      //re-draw datatable with up to date data
      success: () => dataTable.ajax.reload()
    });
  });
  //edit button handler (open up edit form modal)
  $('#example').on('click', '.edit', function(){
    //get clicked row
    const rowClicked = dataTable.row($(this).closest('tr'));
    //populate edit form with row data by corresponding 
    //rowClicked property based on 'data-src' attribute
    $.each($('#editform input'), function(){
      $(this).val(rowClicked.data()[$(this).attr('data-src')]);
    });
    //set modal attribute rowindex to corresponding row index
    $('#editform').attr('rowindex', rowClicked.index());
    //open up edit form modal
    $('#editform').modal('toggle');
  });
  //submit edits handler
  $('#editform').on('click', '#submitedits', function(){
    //grab modified data into object
    const modifiedData = {};
    $.each($('#editform input'), function(){
      Object.assign(modifiedData, {[$(this).attr('data-src')]:$(this).val()});
    });
    //send modified data to the backend
    $.ajax({
      url: '/editrow',
      method: 'POST',
      data: {id: $('#editform').attr('rowindex'), ...modifiedData},
      success: () => {
        //close the modal
        $('#editform').modal('hide');
        //re-draw datatable
        dataTable.ajax.reload();
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <script type="application/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="application/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/937a319e2f.js"></script>
  <script type="application/javascript" src="/main.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">  
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/main.css">
</head>
<body>
  <!-- Table -->
  <table id="example"></table>
  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="editform" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
   <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
     <div class="modal-header">
      <h5 class="modal-title">Row details</h5>
     </div>
     <div class="modal-body">
      <form>
        <div class="form-group"><label>Name:</label><input data-src="name" class="form-control"></input></div>
        <div class="form-group"><label>Title:</label><input data-src="title" class="form-control"></input></div>
      </form>
     </div>
     <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark" id="submitedits">Save changes</button>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your answer is brilliant by the way. I could use it someday myself. But the snippets not loading on my end.  i used the link

Comment: Snippet is not executable as there's no backend for it. You may inspect live demo over [here](https://fmgrt.sse.codesandbox.io/) with the browser's DevTools or take a look at that on [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/editable-bs-modal-datatable-fmgrt?fontsize=14) directly if you're curious about server end as well (which is Node). And if you really liked that method, you may upvote to help it being noticed by the others.

Answer (score 3):

If you mean **JQUERY DATATABLE** then you can insert input fields (that would still retain the cell data) for every column within your table row as you desire and set the borders of the input field to not display, with css.

**EXAMPLE TABLE**

```
 <style>
  .no-input-border {
    border: 'none' !important; background: 'none' !important;
   }
 </style>
 <table id="dynamic_table">
   <thead>
     <tr>
       <th>Name</th>
       <th>State</th>
       <th>Address</th>
       <th>Active</th>
       <th>Action</th> <!-- This column would hold your buttons -->
     </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

**EXAMPLE DATATABLE INITIALIZATION**

```
 var table = $('#dynamic_table').DataTable({
          "order":[[ 0, 'asc' ]], // order by first column
          "processing": true,
          'paging': true,
          'searching': true,
          'retrieve': true,
          'serverSide': true,
          'ajax': {
              'url': "your-ajax-url",
              'type': 'POST'
          },
          'columns': [ //every **name:** value must be present in your json
              { data: null, name: 'name'},
              { data: null, name: 'state' },
              { data: null, name: 'address' },
              { data: null, name: 'active' },
              { data: null, name: 'id' } // column that holds your buttons
          ],
          "columnDefs": [
             {
                "targets": 0,  // column that inserts an input field
                "data":  'name',
                "orderable": false,
                "createdCell": function (td, cellData, rowData, row, col){
                  return '<input type="text" class="no-input-border" name="name" value="'+cellData+'" />'
                }
             },
             {
                "targets": 1,  // column that inserts an input field
                "data":  'state',
                "orderable": false,
                "createdCell": function (td, cellData, rowData, row, col){
                  return '<input type="text" class="no-input-border" name="state" value="'+cellData+'" />'
                }
             },
             {
                "targets": 2,  // column that inserts an input field
                "data":  'address',
                "orderable": false,
                "createdCell": function (td, cellData, rowData, row, col){
                  return '<input type="text" class="no-input-border" name="state" value="'+cellData+'" />'
                }
             },
             {
                "targets": 3,  // column that inserts an input field
                "data":  'active',
                "orderable": false,
                "createdCell": function (td, cellData, rowData, row, col){
                  return '<input type="text" class="no-input-border" name="active" value="'+cellData+'" />'
                }
             },
             {
                "targets": 4,  // column that holds your buttons
                "data":  'id',
                "orderable": false,
                "createdCell": function (td, cellData, rowData, row, col){
                  return '<button class="edit_row">Edit<button>'
                }
             }
          ],
          'responsive': true,
          'initComplete': function(settings, json) {
            //Run a function when table first initializes
          },
          'drawCallback': function( settings ) {
            //Run a function anytime table reloads when paginating
          }
      });
```

**EXAMPLE DATATABLE ROW EDIT FUNCTION**

```
$('#dynamic_table tbody').on('click', '.edit_row', function () {
  var row = table.row( $(this).parents('tr') ); // row that was clicked
  var d = row.data(); // data of the row button that was clicked .eg. console.log(d.name)
  var index = row.index();
  var json = { // json to be sent
        id: d.id,
        name: table.cell(index,0).nodes().to$().find('input').val(),
        state: table.cell(index,1).nodes().to$().find('input').val(),
        address: table.cell(index,2).nodes().to$().find('input').val(),
        active: table.cell(index,3).nodes().to$().find('input').val()
   }
  /*Your Ajax Function Here*/
});
```

**RELOAD DATATABLE FUNCTION**

```
table.ajax.reload( function ( json ) {
  //Run function after table reloads
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure why this answer is upvoted as it **DOES NOT** answer the question. OP requests for freeware *editor* feature which is supposed to edit table data **both** front and back end, while above code does **only** the former.

Comment: I answered it that way because another option is to reload the table to reflect the changes front-end

Comment: I, probably, didn't make my point clear enough: there's nothing in your code that lets to modify underpinning server-side data based on changes you make in the front-end.

Comment: Your post still doesn't answer the OP question: it's about ***edit tooltip***, not *editing in place*, which you try to implement. Another issue is that `table.cell()` refers to `index` parameter which doesn't seem to be defined. And the last issue is that there's no `cell().nodes()` method, to the best of my knowledge, it's `cell().node()`.

Comment: Yes you are right but there is also a provision do it manually, in which case any solution can be provided. And about the ```index``` i'll correct that. You've got sharp eyes sir. I use exactly this same solution myself so i'm sure about the ```cell().nodes()```

Comment: While I appreciate your efforts, bounty hunting with the code that doesn't seem to solve the problem (or even function without errors) is not very promising. The best proof of the concept here would be some live snippet that demonstrates expected result (like the one, I have posted in my answer).

Comment: You don't need to trust my word, you may refer to the docs: it's [`cells().nodes()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/cells().nodes()) or [`cell().node()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/cell().node()), but not `cell().nodes()`

Comment: And by *doing manually* OP means *implement that exact feature without plug-in*, I may suspect.

Comment: You could be right, but the solution I provided ```cell().nodes()``` is what i myself use all the time and it works for me. I didn't review my answer calmly enough, so that's why i had lots of oversights.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195923/discussion-between-ikechukwu-kalu-and-u25lywt5iejhc3rhcmqg).

Comment: Thanks for reply. It doesn't work completely. but,  It was really helpful.

Comment: @HaniyeShadman sorry about that i didn't test it. Hope you've solved your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom button in datatable. You can go to this [documentation](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/initialisation/custom.html) to know how it works. Now in the action you can call some function inside it when the user click it the button will call the function in javascript and do what you want inside it.

Here's example code.

```
$('#table_id').DataTable({
"serverSide": true,
"processing": true,
"ajax": function (data, callback, settings) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/some url',
        type: 'GET',
        data: data,
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data)
        }
    });

    },
   buttons: [
    { text: 'Add', name: 'btnAdd', action: function ( e, dt, node, config ) {
                $.fn.addfunction();
            }},
    { extend: 'selected', text: 'Edit', name: 'btnEdit', action: function ( e, dt, node, config ) {
                $.fn.editfunction();
            }},
    { extend: 'selected',  text: 'Delete', name: 'btnDelete', action: function ( e, dt, node, config ) {
                $.fn.deletefunction();
            }},
   ],
   "columns": [{
        "title": "edit",
        "data": null,
        "className": "center",
        "defaultContent": '<a href = "" class = "editor_edit"> Edit </a>  /  <a href = "" class = "editor_remove"> Delete </a>'
     }, {
        "title": "name",
        "data": "name"
     }, {
        "title": "id",
        "data": "id"
     },

    ]
});

$.fn.addfunction = function(){
//Your code here
}

$.fn.editfunction = function(){
//Your code here
}

$.fn.deletefunction = function(){
//Your code here
}
```

I added the idea of this [document from datatables](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/initialisation/custom.html) that create custom button and create and call function in [jquery](https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/faq/how-to-define-a-function-in-jquery.php)

There's also other way by using and giving id for the button. here's the example:

```
$('#table_id').DataTable({
    "serverSide": true,
    "processing": true,
    "ajax": function (data, callback, settings) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/some url',
            type: 'GET',
            data: data,
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data)
            }
        });

        },
       buttons: [
        { text: 'Add', name: 'btnAdd', 
        attr:{
         id: 'btnAdd'
        }},
        { extend: 'selected',  text: 'Edit', name: 'btnEdit', 
        attr:{
         id: 'btnEdit'
        }},
        { extend: 'selected',  text: 'Delete', name: 'btnDelete', 
        attr:{
         id: 'btnDelete'
        }},
       ],
       "columns": [{
            "title": "edit",
            "data": null,
            "className": "center",
            "defaultContent": '<a href = "" class = "editor_edit"> Edit </a>  /  <a href = "" class = "editor_remove"> Delete </a>'
        }, {
            "title": "name",
            "data": "name"
        }, {
            "title": "id",
            "data": "id"
        },

       ]
    });

    $(document).on('click', '#btnAdd', function(e)
        {
          e.preventDefault();
          e.stopPropagation();
          //your code here
        });

    $(document).on('click', '#btnEdit', function(e)
        {
          e.preventDefault();
          e.stopPropagation();
          //your code here
        });

    $(document).on('click', '#btnDelete', function(e)
            {
              e.preventDefault();
              e.stopPropagation();
              //your code here
            });
```

Sorry for many **Edit** Hope it helps!

Comment: What do you mean? you can do that using that one. just use selected option

Comment: I updated my answer with example code. if you still don't solved it try it.