# enable edit/delete in Datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-cloud-firestore, datatables

I have a web app with cloud firestore as my backend. I used [DataTable](https://datatables.net/) to export data from cloud firestore and display on the webpage, and the table looks like this:
[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/co6l5.png)

The code to load "orders" collection from cloud firestore and append to DataTables is:

```
var dataTable;

db.collection("orders").orderBy('timestamp', 'desc')
    .get()
    .then(function (querySnapshot) {
        if (querySnapshot.size) {
            var firestore_source = [];
            querySnapshot.forEach(function (data) {
                var obj = data.data();
                obj.id = data.id;
                firestore_source.push(obj);
            });
            //console.log('data:', firestore_source);
            dataTable.clear();
            dataTable.rows.add(firestore_source);
            dataTable.order([0, 'desc']).draw();
        }
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
    });


$(document).ready(function () {
    dataTable = $('#example').DataTable({
        columns: [
            { data: 'Name' },
            { data: "Date" },
            { data: "Ins" },
            { data: "Phone" },
            { data: "Item" },
            { data: "Price"},
            { data: "Commision"},
            { data: "Revenue"},
            {
                data: null,
                className: "center",
                defaultContent: '<a href="" class="editor_edit">Edit</a> / <a href="" class="editor_remove">Delete</a>'
            }
        ],
        "columnDefs": [
            {"className": "dt-center", "targets": "_all"}
          ],
    });

    
    $('#example').on('click', 'a.editor_remove', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log("delete clicked");
        console.log($(this).closest('tr'));
         
         // what I should do here?

    } );
});
```

And datatables in HTML:

```
        <table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Customer</th>
                    <th>Order Date</th>
                    <th>Instagram</th>
                    <th>Phone</th>
                    <th>Item</th>
                    <th>Price $</th>
                    <th>Commission</th>
                    <th>Earnings $</th>
                    <th>Edit / Delete</th> 
                </tr>
            </thead>

        </table>
```

Currently, the entire data within "orders" collection is loaded and obviously there are no features like editing and deleting data in each row.
So, I am stuck here that I have no idea **how to identify each row in my table when clicking the edit/delete buttons on that row**, so that I can use it as parameters to query cloud firestore?

I saw that there is built in tool [Editor](https://editor.datatables.net/), but I am looking for native methods.

Comment: You may check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56866584/11299053) for some clues

Comment: thanks. I think this is what I was after

Comment: You're welcome. If that was helpful, feel free to upvote that post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding datatable API, You can get the clicked/selected row's data by this code which means you can get identity to edit or remove the selected row.

```
$('#example tbody').on('click', 'a.editor_remove', function () {
    let row = dataTable.api().row($(this).closest("tr")).data();
    console.log(row);
});
```

Comment: In my case using `dataTable.api()` will incur _Uncaught_ error, so just use `let row = dataTable.row($(this).closest("tr")).data();` will work